# How do I remove a reminder from an event so it updates the event in the provider not just the sqlite db?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-calendar

I tried deleting a reminder for an event by using this code:

```
int result = getContentResolver().delete(
Reminders.CONTENT_URI, 
Reminders.EVENT_ID + " = ?",
new String[] { "44" }
);
```

This shows it deleted 1 row. However, when I view the event in the calendar app, the reminder is still there. Even if I updated the "hasAlarm" field, I don't think it will update the event in Exchange. How do I properly (using Ice Cream Sandwich - API 14 - or later) remove a reminder from a calendar event?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting , try with update query , it works . IF it doesn't work lemme know i'll try to help with code snippet.

Comment: I did the update (with hasAlarm=0) but that only offers the ability to remove all reminders, not a specific one. Is there a way to remove specific reminders?

Comment: you need to update only when hasalarm is true , then  remove the reminders , run the update query I hope it works for you.